# W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.140.204 80]

Tags: debian, apt, docker, aptitude, node.js

I'm trying to get a project running locally on Deepin. The project relies on node 6.10, I understand that it's an old version but it works.
When the Dockerfile tries to run the sudo apt-get update, it gives the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.140.204 80]
```

The weird thing is that I just deployed it yesterday on a Macbook without such an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: _@Muhammad Asif_, this could just be a temporary issue. Please try again after another cuppa coffee.

Comment: I have it as well